# incorporating theme into react-minimal-pie-chart does not work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react-minimal-pie-chart to create some pie charts in my https://github.com/toomuchdesign/react-minimal-pie-chart

I am using Material-UI for UI and want to use themes to add colors to pie chart

```
import PieChart from 'react-minimal-pie-chart';

<PieChart
        data={[{
          title: 'One',
          value: 82,
          color: '#007DCD'
        }]}
        totalValue={100}
        lineWidth={20}
        label
        labelStyle={{
          fontSize: '25px'
        }}
        labelPosition={0}
      />
```

I tried replacing this with

```
import PieChart from 'react-minimal-pie-chart';
<PieChart
        data={[{
          title: 'One',
          value: 82,
          color: theme.palette.secondary.main
        }]}
        totalValue={100}
        lineWidth={20}
        label
        labelStyle={{
          fontSize: '25px'
        }}
        labelPosition={0}
      />
```

But it does not work. Would like suggestions on how to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you are customizing colors you have to create a theme variable and wrap your component inside a `MuiThemeProvider` like this:

```
import PieChart from "react-minimal-pie-chart";
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: purple[500] },
    secondary: { main: '#11cb5f' },
  },
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <PieChart
        data={[
          {
            title: "One",
            value: 82,
            color: theme.palette.secondary.main
          }
        ]}
        totalValue={100}
        lineWidth={20}
        label
        labelStyle={{
          fontSize: "25px"
        }}
        labelPosition={0}
      />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

I was able to change the chart color using `theme.palette.primary.main` and `theme.palette.secondary.main`, the code can be seen [here](https://repl.it/repls/MaroonDangerousRam).